# Resolve ambiguous structures in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I have two programs
One creats a structure and one resolves it

the structure is as follows

```
class A {
    List<B>
}

class B {
    List<A>
}
```

Now the problem is that the program that creates the structure is not sure whether the structure is

```
A1->B1
 |->B2->A2
     |->A3->B3->A4
```

OR

```
A1->B1
 |->B3->A4
 |->B2->A2
     |->A3
```

Could someone please provide a way to pass this ambiguity whether B3 is attached to A1 or A3 such that the second program can know that there is an ambiguity and can decide which structure to use depending on some constraint.

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Seems to me that neither of those two examples fits the data structure given by that code. Each `B` needs to have three `A`s.

Comment: You can consider that the other A's are null..have edited the question so that B now has a List of A's

Comment: @pratikvasa To second Borat here, "what are you trying to do?" Is A1/B1/whatever even a specific identity that you're trying to keep track of, and, if so, what structure are you actually trying to use and why?

Comment: I don't see any ambiguity here. Perhaps you just have not completely understood your problem?!

Comment: @pratikvasa the difference in your example is `A1->B2->A3->B3->A4` vs `A1->B3->A4`, can you add the code that generate these structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could represent the structure as a graph with two kinds of nodes (A and B) and two kinds of links (from A to B and the other way around).

```
class A {}

class B {}

class Link<F,T> {
    F from;
    T to;
}

class Structure {
    List<A> a;
    List<B> b;
    List<Link<A,B>> a2b;
    List<Link<B,A>> b2a;
}
```

Constraints should ensure that links are only between nodes of the graph.

The ambiguity would be represented by multiple links towards the same node.

Answer (score 0):

If these really are the only two structures you'll encounter, then you can just check how many elements A1 has:

```
boolean useFirstStructure = (A1.size()==2);
```

With the second structure, you'll have `A1.size()==3`.

CKuck's answer is the right way to handle more general structures, though.

Answer (score -1):

If you initiate your code like:

```
 new A(
   List(
     new B(List()),
     new B(
       List(
           new A(List()),
           new A(List(new B(List(new A())
           )
       )
    )
 )
```

You'll get

```
A1->B1
 |->B2->A2
     |->A3->B3->A4
```

If you initiate your code like this:

```
 new A(
   List(
     new B(List(new A(List())),
     new B(List(new A(List()),
     new B(List(new A(List()), new A(List())))
```

You'll get

```
A1->B1
 |->B3->A4
 |->B2->A2
     |->A3
```

You'll be able to serialize and deserialize both representations.

What is it you mean by ambiguity?

Comment: No the initialization is not the problem. The problem is that we want only one of the structures, but the program creating the structure does not know which is the correct one..so what we want is that the first program sends the structure in such a way that the second program can infer that the first program was not able to decide the correct structure and it has to decide what the structure is depending on some constraints..so is there some easy way for the 1st program to communicate with the second program that there is an ambiguity and these are the 2 possibilities..

Comment: Whatever the problem at hand, you might be overcomplicating it.

If you can't determine in which structure to deserialze, that means, you have problems with your serialization format.

If you are using standard serialization mechanism, there is no such problem.

And besides, If the program can't decide the structure, you can't guarantee results, and practically introduce random behaviour to the system, which should never be desired.

Comment: @pratikvasa Wait, so, you want a program that can determine the structure that another program has to... wait... no, I'm confused. If program A has two possibilities than it takes program B a channel of 1 bit to figure out how program A is sending it's information. I'm entirely confused about what you're asking.